# (c++) cicle for output looped

Tags: c++, for-loop

Given a base and an exponent, calculate "high exponent base". Be the base of that
the exponent are integer values. Use the "for"
Input: base, exponent
Output: high exponent base

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath> // Libreria necessaria per la funzione pow

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Variabili 
int base, esponente, elevazione,n;

cout<<"Inserisci la base:";
cin>>base;
cout<<"Inserisci l'esponente:";
cin>>esponente;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
elevazione=pow(base,esponente);
cout<<"Il risultato è:"<<elevazione;
}
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}
```

On Linux terminal i keep getting the result like in a loop. How can i stop the cicle for and give me only one time the result?

Comment: Why do you *have* a loop? What is the purpose of it? And you use `n` in the loop condition, without initializing it, which means its value is *indeterminate* and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: you want to know how you can not write a for loop? Not clear what you are asking

Comment: my guess is that your assignment was asking you to calculate the power by hand using a loop and not to use a loop that uses `pow` (and prints the same result for an undefined number of times ;)

Answer (score 1):

you are not initializing the `n` variable. In this way, it can assume whatever value (say 1254445588). So you are printing n times the same "Il risultato è ...".

If you need to use a loop, the right solution is:

```
int result = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < esponente; i++)
{
    result *= base;
}

std::cout << "Il risultato è: " << result << std::endl;
```

Get rid of `n`

Comment: " it can assume whatever value" is a bit misleading. What the compiler actually assumes is that undefined behaviour never happens, so if there is undefined behaviour the compiler is free to do whatever it feels like (including, but not limited to picking any value for `n`)

Comment: @tobi303 can you explain "undefined behaviour never happens"? Is it true for every compiler?

Comment: if your code has undefined behaviour then it is not a valid c++ program, so yes any compiler may assume that in a valid c++ program there is no undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ok, but the value of n is not set by the compiler, isn't it? The compiler takes the value stored in the location of the stack that refers to n, which is not predictable. If what i say is true, i can't still understand "picking any value for n"

Comment: it is undefined behaviour because `n` is used uninitialized. Strictly speaking thats all one can say for sure about the code. One cannot reason about code that contains ub in a meaningful way, because once you break the rules, there arent any rules anymore. Assuming `n` will have a value that was stored in the location of the stack that `n` refers to is dangerous at best. You can experiment and try to see what a particular compiler will do with the situation, but thats nothing to rely on, because it may change at any time